# Checking if a method is declared in an interface

Tags: java, reflection

I want to check if a method of a class is declared in an interface.

AInterface.java:

```java
public interface AInterface {
    Object hi();
}
```

AClass.java:

```java
public class AClass implements AInterface {
    public String hi() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method md : AClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("Declaring class: " + md.getDeclaringClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Return type: " + md.getReturnType().getName());
            System.out.println("Name: " + md.getName());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

`md.getDeclaringClass()` returns the same class for both methods. So how do I check which one is in the class?

Comment: I've read your question several times, but I don't know what you are asking.  Is your question "How do I determine which method on which class will be called at runtime?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want to know what method is in the class, not the interface.

Comment: Assuming the method conforms to the interface, it's going to have the same name.  You need to ask your question in a different way, or read https://xyproblem.info.

Comment: The method truly is declared both on the interface and the class. Unfortunately, there's no good way to discover if a method is implementing/overriding another method from a supertype. You have to check both places and potentially also look for covariant parameter types. Yes, it is as awful as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare the class and the interface, this way:

```java
Class<?> clazz = AClass.class;
Class<?> interfce = AInterface.class;

for (Method method : interfce.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    Method overriddenMethod = null;

    // Iterate
    for (Method classMethod : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (classMethod.getName().equals(method.getName())) {
            Class<?>[] interfaceParameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
            Class<?>[] classParameterTypes = classMethod.getParameterTypes();

            if (Arrays.equals(interfaceParameterTypes, classParameterTypes) && classMethod.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())) {
                overriddenMethod = classMethod;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Output to illustrate
     */
    System.out.print("Method " + method.getName() + "(");
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(parameterTypes[i].getSimpleName());
        if (i < parameterTypes.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(") ");

    // Class Method
    if (overriddenMethod != null) {
        System.out.println("is overridden");

        // Interface Method (not implemented)
    } else {
        System.out.println("is not overridden");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Method hi() is overridden
```

But, if you create `BClass`:

```java
public abstract class BClass implements AInterface {
    
}
```

And use it to compare, the output will be:

```
Method hi() is not overridden
```

This code matches the method argument types too, so if you change the interface to:

```java
public interface AInterface {
    Object hi();

    Object hi(String str);
}
```

And then create `CClass`:

```java
public abstract class CClass implements AInterface {
    @Override
    public Object hi(String var) {
        return var;
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Method hi() is not overridden
Method hi(String) is overridden
```

Comment: This is not sufficient.  You need to match the method argument types, too.  Imagine a class which implements Runnable, and which also has a `public void run(String s)` method.

Comment: You can simply use `clazz.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes())` to find out whether there is an overriding/implementing method. No need to loop over the methods yourself.

Comment: @VGR You're totally right! Thank you for the recommendation, I've improved my answer.

Comment: @Holger this method doesn't work when you have `Object hi()` in the interface and `public String hi()` in the implementation for example.

Comment: @DiegoBorba what behavior do you expect and what do you get? The method `String hi()` does override the method `Object hi()` and the lookup based on name and parameter types will find that.